# How do I determine the signature of a method in a Matlab class?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I'm accessing a .NET API through Matlab.  I'm using a class that has an exposed method, but the signature seems to not match the documentation (or I don't understand the documentation!).

When I perform a call in Matlab I get:

```
K>> Surface.ChangeType(ZOSAPI.Editors.LDE.SurfaceType.CoordinateBreak)
No method 'ChangeType' with matching signature found for class 'ZemaxUI.ZOSAPI.Editors.ZOSAPI_LDERow'.
```

I can tell the method exists for the class using:

```
methods(Surface)
```

However, I cannot understand what aspect of the signature I'm violating.

*Is there a command in Matlab (or a way to probe the DLL with Visual Studio) to reveal the signature of the method?*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a decompiler to see contents of a `.dll` file and understand how to call it. Some Free decompilers:

http://ilspy.net/

https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

http://www.devextras.com/decompiler/

Update:

And I've forgot that you could also use `methodsview` function which displays a window with more information.

Answer (score 0):

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/methods.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop

I think (method) is correct but you will probably need the overload (method,'-full').  Its do you know the full namespace for that class?

If you just need the information then i would just use a free decomplier as is mentioned above :)